# .NET Core 2.1 Set Environment Variables for Development Environment and IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I would like some clarification on whether the Environment Variables I set in Visual Studio 2017 which end up in launchSettings.json are similar to the ones I set in my Windows 10 System Variables and the ones on the IIS Configuration Manager?

I would like to use Environment Variables on my app but I need its location to be consistent. On my local laptop, if I set it on the Windows 10 System Variables or User Variables, Would my app be able to pick up the same variables if I set it on my Windows Server 2012?

Alternatively, if I set it in Visual Studio which ends up in launchSettings.json, won't it keep getting erased everytime I update the app?

Lastly, with the IIS Configuration, I understand I can read variables from there, but where can I set them on my local laptop?

Here are some images for reference

Visual Studio (launchSettings.json)

[image]

Windows 10 System Variables

[image]

IIS Configuration Variables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

launchSettings.json is only being used when running via visual studio. This has nothing to do with IIS.

When planning on using env. variables in production (IIS), you should use System Variable. See docs for more:
[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2)